# Launch a model when the session is close - Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, save

I build a neural network with two hidden layer. When I launch the session i save the session by :

```
saver.save(sess, "model.ckpt")
```

If I remain in the same session and I launch this code:

```
restorer=tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    restorer.restore(sess,"./prova")
    new_graph = tf.train.import_meta_graph('prova.meta') 
    new_graph.restore(sess, 'prova.ckpt')
    feed={
        pred1.inputs:test_data,
        pred1.is_training:False
    }
    test_predict=sess.run(pred1.predicted,feed_dict=feed)
```

I can launch the model for the test.

The question is: there is a method for launch the model when the session is close? In particulary, I save my train result in .ckpt, I can re-launch the model in another moment?

Comment: Why don't you want to start another session in test time?

Comment: At the moment is the same start a new session with train or test set. what i want is understand if is possible start a new session with the date in salved in ckpt file; and, if is it possible, how can do this. Thanks

Comment: You have provided the snippet, in which you restore a model within a new session. There's no training there. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: The training is before. My question is: if i launch session.close() it's possible re-launch the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run the model outside of `tf.Session`. The quote from [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session):

> A Session object encapsulates the environment in which Operation objects are executed, and Tensor objects are evaluated.

But you can easily open and close the sessions many times, use an existing graph or load a previously saved graph, and use it in a *new session*. Here's a slightly modified [example from the doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model):

```
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", shape=[3], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", shape=[5], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)

inc_v1 = v1.assign(v1+1)
dec_v2 = v2.assign(v2-1)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  inc_v1.op.run()
  dec_v2.op.run()
  save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print("Model restored.")
  print("v1 : %s" % v1.eval())
  print("v2 : %s" % v2.eval())
```

Between these two sessions you can't evaluate `v1` and `v2`, but you can right after starting a new session.